# Find and Replace in Mongo using Regex

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a collection in Mongo with a shape such as:

```
  {
    path: 'any string', // e.g., 'a,b,c,d,e'
  }
```

I need to find and replace `'a'` in all documents in this collection with another string, e.g., `'1,2,3'`. I know this can be done very inefficiently using a `find()`, iterating through the results, and updating those in the db. Is there some sort of aggregate or bulk operation that can make this operation easier/faster (I'm using Mongoose)? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there some sort of aggregate or bulk operation that can make this operation easier/faster

You could run MongoDB [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) to process the find and replace, then iterate through the result and send [unordered bulk update operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp/#db.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp).

I'll write the examples below in [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) to keep it generic, but for [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) equivalent please see - [Model.aggregate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) and [Model.bulkWrite()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite) for more information.

For example, if you have three documents as below:

```
{ "_id": 1, "path": "a,b,c,d" } 
{ "_id": 2, "path": "b,a,c,d" }
{ "_id": 3, "path": "c,b,a" }
```

Where you would like to replace `a` with `1,2,3`. Using aggregation pipeline, create a new field called `newPath` to store the substituted result, as below:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$addFields":{
        "toBeRemoved": "a",
        "replacement": "1,2,3",
    }},  
    {"$addFields":{
        "newPath": {
            "$concat":[
                {"$substrBytes":[
                    "$path", 
                    0, 
                    { "$cond": { 
                            "if": { 
                                "$lt": [ {"$subtract": [{"$strLenBytes": "$path"}, {"$subtract": [ {"$strLenBytes": "$path"}, {"$indexOfBytes":["$path", "$toBeRemoved"]} ] } ]}, 0]
                            }, 
                            "then": 0,
                            "else": {"$subtract": [{"$strLenBytes": "$path"}, {"$subtract": [ {"$strLenBytes": "$path"}, {"$indexOfBytes":["$path", "$toBeRemoved"]} ] } ]}
                        }
                    }]}, 
                "$replacement", 
                {"$substrBytes":[
                    "$path", 
                    {"$add":[{ 
                        "$cond": { 
                            "if": { 
                                "$lt": [ {"$subtract": [{"$strLenBytes": "$path"}, {"$subtract": [ {"$strLenBytes": "$path"}, {"$indexOfBytes":["$path", "$toBeRemoved"]} ] } ]}, 0]
                            }, 
                            "then": 0,
                            "else": {"$subtract": [{"$strLenBytes": "$path"}, {"$subtract": [ {"$strLenBytes": "$path"}, {"$indexOfBytes":["$path", "$toBeRemoved"]} ] } ]}
                        }
                        }, {"$strLenBytes": "$toBeRemoved"}
                    ]}, 
                    {"$subtract": [
                        {"$strLenBytes": "$path"}, 
                        {"$add": [ 
                            {"$indexOfBytes":["$path", "$toBeRemoved"]}, 
                            {"$strLenBytes": "$toBeRemoved"} 
                        ]} 
                    ]}
                ]}
            ]
        },
    }}, 
    {"$project": {
        "toBeRemoved":0, 
        "replacement":0,
    }}
])
```

This will output something as below:

```
{ "_id": 1, "path": "a,b,c,d", "newPath": "1,2,3,b,c,d" }
{ "_id": 2, "path": "b,a,c,d", "newPath": "b,1,2,3,c,d" }
{ "_id": 3, "path": "c,b,a",   "newPath": "c,b,1,2,3" }
```

Please note that the aggregation above has been written so that it can be re-used for other substitution. i.e. replaced `toBeRemoved` with `b` and `replacement` with `x,y` and it would work similarly.

The aggregation pipeline above should work for MongoDB v3.4+. Also worth mentioning that currently there's an open ticket [SERVER-11947](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-11947) to add regex support to the aggregation language.

You can then iterate through the result, and send unordered `bulkWrite` update operations, with an example below:

```
db.collection.bulkWrite(
     [
       { "updateOne" :
          {
             "filter" : { "_id" : 1},
             "update" : { "$set" : { "path" : <newPath value> } }
          }
       }, 
       { "updateOne" :
          {
             "filter" : { "_id" : 2},
             "update" : { "$set" : { "path" : <newPath value> } }
          }
       }, 
)
```

Comment: Awesome...thank you! I just got the bulkWrite part working yesterday, but hadn't had a chance to update my question. This is what I was looking for though...thanks again.